# How to do SVG translation when using time scale on X-axis in D3

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to do simple real time graph from my server, for that I'm using d3 with timeseries.
The problem is that I can't do translate(x(-1000)), because x() expects a date, how to overcome that and make the translating work?
Here's the code:

```
    var data = [];

    var curDate = new Date();
    var df = d3.time.format.utc('%Y-%m-%d');

    var margin = {top: 6, right: 0, bottom: 6, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.right,
    height = 240 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("p").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .style("margin-left", -margin.left + "px")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    function draw() {
        var x = d3.time.scale.utc().domain([new Date(data[0].year), new Date(data[data.length-1].year)]).range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 5]).rangeRound([0, height]);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate('basis')
        .x(function(d, i) { return x(d.year); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.books);});

        svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);


        var path = svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .append('path')
        .data([data])
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('d', line);
        tick(path, svg, line, x);
    }

    var data = [];

    var curDate = new Date();
    var df = d3.time.format.utc('%Y-%m-%d');

    var margin = {top: 6, right: 0, bottom: 6, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.right,
    height = 240 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("p").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .style("margin-left", -margin.left + "px")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    function draw() {
        var x = d3.time.scale.utc().domain([new Date(data[0].year), new Date(data[data.length-1].year)]).range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 5]).rangeRound([0, height]);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate('basis')
        .x(function(d, i) { return x(d.year); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.books);});

        svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);


        var path = svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .append('path')
        .data([data])
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('d', line);
        tick(path, svg, line, x);
    }
    function tick(path, svg, line, x) {
        data.push({year: new Date(data[data.length-1].year.getTime() + 2000), books: 5*Math.random()});
        path
        .attr('d', line)
        .attr('transform', null)
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .ease('linear')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(-3600*24) + ')')
        .each('end', function() { tick(path, svg, line, x); });
        data.shift();
    }

    d3.text('server.' + df(new Date()) + '.txt', 'text/plain', function(text) {
        var lines = text.split("\n");
        for (var i in lines) {
            if (lines[i].trim().length == 0) continue;
            var lineData = lines[i].split(' ');
            data.push({year: new Date(parseInt(lineData[0])), books: parseFloat(lineData[1])});
        }
        draw();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x [maps](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#wiki-scale) values in the date range you specified to [0, width]. With:

```
path
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(-3600*24) + ')')
```

it looks like you're trying to move path over the distance of one day. `-3600*24` isn't a date though, so you're getting nonsense results.

To find to distance of a day, you need to find the scaled difference between two dates a day apart:

```
x(new Date(0)) - x(new Date(24*3600*1000))
```

Before trying to do too much more, you might also want to read up on [date objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) in javascript; I suspect `new Date(data[0].year)` isn't what you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks, now when I see it it's obvious, but I couldn't come up with it :) As for the data[0].year, the nam is wrong because it actually contains unix timestamp.